# PictureBox Missed In the .exe VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have A pictureBox in a form

I have declared a Picture box called Then

```
 Field.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\ABK\Desktop\Othello\field.png") 
 Field.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(483, 610)
```

Then I added the picbox to the form but when i copy the exr into another computer I don't see the picture

when I copy the exe into another computer I cannot see the picture
how can I include it in the exe file 
Please try to keep the answers as simple as possible and demonstrate with examples

Comment: It’s hard to tell what’s going wrong without any details, but if you’ve hard-coded a path to an image, put it in your project’s resources instead (My Project > Resources) and select that resource as the `PictureBox`’s `Image` in the property window.

Comment: I have declared a Picture box
Then 
Field.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\ABK\Desktop\Othello\field.png")
        Field.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(483, 610)
Then I added the picbox to the form but when i copy the exr into another computer i don't see the picture

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  We have no idea where the code gets the image from so we cant tell you whats wrong without the code.

Comment: Okay, you’ll want to add it to your resources and set `Field.Image = My.Resources.fieldImage`.

Comment: Ryan I am very thankful 
But how can i add a picturebox to My resources

Comment: You add the *image* not the control

Comment: This is the picture Link "C:\Users\ABK\Desktop\Othello\field.png"
how can I add it ?

Comment: Why are you not setting the `Image()` property **directly** through the IDE?...

Answer (score 0):

click on your form.

the properties tab should be on the bottom right

find image or background image and click on it

click the ... on the right side.

[image as example of instructions above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s58Fh.jpg)

a menu should show up.

Click import then select the file you want saved,

then press open it should go back to the menu,

select (none) to set your form image back to normal,

[image as example of instructions above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Kcf.jpg)

then press ok,

go back to your code and change

`Field.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\ABK\Desktop\Othello\field.png")`

to `Field.Image = My.Resources.field`

This should keep the image when you give it to your friend

Comment: if your properties tab isnt in the bottom right, right click the form and click on properties there

Comment: This is what i got from you question.

I have got a PictureBox in the form.

I want to change the image this is how i'm currently doing it.

`Field.Image=Image.FromFile("C:\Users\ABK\Desktop\Othello\field.png")`

 `Field.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(483, 610)`

But when when I copied the exe to different computer, I cannot see the picture.

How can I include the Picture in the exe file. 

Please try to keep the answers as simple as possible and demonstrate with examples